# How to check first preceding-sibling is w:tbl of the context node in xslt 2.0?

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, xslt-2.0, xpath-2.0

This is XML Document.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
        <w:document xmlns:w="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main"
                    xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml">
        <w:body>

          <w:p>para1</w:p>
          <w:tbl>table data 1</w:tbl>
          <w:p>para2</w:p>   <!-- have to check whether this node is w:tbl or not  with respect to the context node below-->
          <w:tbl>table data 2</w:tbl> <!-- Assume this is context node -->

       </w:body>
      </w:document>
```

So, I want to check the **first preceding-sibling[`<w:p>para2</w:p>`]** of the **context node[`<w:tbl>table data 2</w:tbl>`]** is **`<w:tbl`>** or not.

Please Guide me to get out of this issue...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you are asking for

```
<xsl:if test="preceding-sibling::*[1]/self::w:p">....</xsl:if>
```